# Typescript: Strongly type incoming array with variable types

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, serialization, interface

I have a JSON array which can contain either of two types defined by `IPerson` and `ICompany`.

```
[ 
            { "Name"  : "Bob", "Age" : 50, "Address": "New Jersey"},
            { "Name"  : "ABC Inc", "Founded" : 1970, "CEO": "Alice" }
]
```

This data is received from an endpoint. I want to map this data exactly in same way in my client application in Typescript. How should I define my model in this case.

I know we can define same interfaces in TypeScript but is it possible to have an array that holds either of two objects defined by `IPerson` and `ICompany` and know the type of each item while iterating the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an `Array<IPerson | ICompany>`. For iterating, you can do something like this

```js
function iterateMyArray(array: Array<IPerson | ICompany>) {
  array.forEach(item => {
     if ('Age' in item) {
        // item is an person
        console.log(item.Address);
     } else {
        // item is a company
     }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also trying to use `instanceOf` to make it cleaner, but it doesn't work with interfaces.

Comment: Is there a better alternative to `if ('Age' in item)` ?

Comment: `instanceOf` only works with class, since type / interface does not exist in runtime

Comment: I don't see a better alternative. `in` operator is simple enough. These are options for differentiating types : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: typeguard is definitely your friend here. it'll help typescript to know what exact type you'll be operating on after the type guard and make it much safer.